Audit service does not audit commands
OS sles 15, audit service enabled
When I issue any command (for example, date or ls), I expect it to be logged in audit.log, something like this:
type=SYSCALL msg=audit...
type=EXECVE msg=audit(1718094805.867:24632): argc=1 a0="date"
...
but these entries are not in audit.log
There are other entries there, for example about the start/finish of sessions, but there are no commands called.

What audit rules do you have enabled? Try auditctl -l.

date or ls is not a security relevant command; your expectations of auditd seem to be that of a keylogger if you expect it to capture any command.

https://lowendbox.com/blog/how-to-audit-every-command-run-on-your-linux-system/
basically do this to put this rule in your  /etc/audit/rules.d/audit.rules file
auditctl -a exit,always -F arch=b32 -S execve -k allcmds
auditctl -a exit,always -F arch=b64 -S execve -k allcmds

be aware the /var/log/audit/audit.log file might grow to gigabytes in a few minutes, and simply fill up whatever disk partition that folder is on.
And I believe that will capture every command on a running system including all under the hood stuff.  If you want every command done by a specific user, then it would be a matter of tailoring the rule to filter on a specific uid= such as
auditctl -a exit,always -F arch=b32 -F uid=1234 -S execve -k allcmds

or
auditctl -a exit,always -F arch=b32 -F uid >=1000 -S execve -k allcmds


first I removed -a never,task from the rules
and then added these commands and it helped
